# Autofill table based on userform, when data comes from the other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to get the result in the table, where the data comes from my userform.

Column H comprises the sum of column G from my active worksheet and column AD from my external worksheet, which is "Formulas".

[image]

I have the userform, to fill my whole row in the table as I input some data in this userform.

Column H won't be input directly from the Userform, because it includes the formula mentioned above.

I want to auto-populate column H, when making input to adjacent column G and also column L.

This auto-population must be based on the formula described above, where the column AD from the "Formulas" sheet is based on the IF statement as shown in the picture below. This IF statement is related to column L from my active worksheet, determining the integer value ranges.

[image]

For this purpose, I used the following code for making the input from my userform. Modifying it further by inserting the potential solution for the aforementioned column H auto-population.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet, wkf As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
AppendToColumn wks, "A", JobID.Text  'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last Blank Row
AppendToColumn wks, "B", CoordName.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "C", PlannerName.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "D", Surveyor.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "E", RRGuy.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "F", DateBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "G", TimeBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "I", AddressBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "J", CityBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "K", PostcodeBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "L", THPBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "M", JointBox.Text

Dim lastrowG As Long, ListIndex As Long
lastrowG = AppendToColumn(wks, "G", TimeBox.Text)
lastrowAD = wks.Range("AD" & ListIndex + 1)
AppendToColumn wks, "H", ("=G" & lastrowG & " + Formulas!AD" & lastrowAD)  

MsgBox ("All data has been added successfully")
End Sub


Private Function AppendToColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                       ByVal column As Variant, _
                       ByVal value As Variant, _
                       Optional ByVal kindOfValue As DataType = DataValue) As Long
'--- copies the given value to the first empty cell in the
'    specified column. the "column" value can be either numeric
'    or alphabetic. RETURNS the index of the last row
Dim colIndex As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
With ws
    '--- quick conversion to make sure we have a numeric column index
    colIndex = IIf(IsNumeric(column), column, .Cells(1, column).Column)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    '--- if the column is completely empty, the first empty row is 1,
    '    otherwise it's one row down from the last row
    firstEmptyRow = IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(lastRow, colIndex)), 1, lastRow + 1)
    Select Case kindOfValue
    Case DataValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).value = value
    Case FormulaValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).Formula = value
    End Select
End With
AppendToColumn = lastRow
End Function
```

I am getting error:

> Type mismatch

indicating the following lines:

```
lastrowAD = wks.Range("AD" & ListIndex + 1)
AppendToColumn wks, "H", ("=G" & lastrowG & " + Formulas!AD" & lastrowAD)
```

Comment: Always put `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. Declare all of your variables. You didn't declare `Dim ListIndex As Long` anywhere. That's what the error means.

Comment: In your second example you pass two variables to a Sub that requires three, also a very clear error.

Comment: Your hint was good, but it's still something missing here. i updated the query, you can see.

Comment: LastRowAD is declared as a Long but you assigned a Range object to it. That is indeed a type mismatch. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to populate the H column based on the formula G+AD, whereas AD is based on the different sheets. All of them work on the same basis, once I am filling u the form, the following row is filling up.

Comment: Could you help me? I need it today? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, this question is all over the place. It is not clear what your problem is at this point. I've already solved multiple problems and you keep asking more questions. This website is not a forum. It's a Q&A site where you ask one, clear, question that has one clear answer. To avoid frustration please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I always ask a clear question, which includes the code, image, and problem. I don't understand why can't you get my point. The issue is clear from my point of view. I need the valid sum of two columns, where one is based on the active sheet and another one on the external sheet. Every question might help the descendants, who will visit this website, so I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Except you listed two errors in your original post, both which have been solved. One question, one answer. If you have a new question you should ask a new question.

Comment: No, It's still the same issue. I just only tried to make a formula coming from my active sheet instead of an external one. As a result, I got the formula =G15 + S0.
I know, that the policy of this website is Q & A and I am doing my best to stick on it. I only update my queries, when see some similar approaches to the same problem.

Comment: @HackSlash I rebuilt this question totally. Now It should match the "How to ask" guidelines and be more precise for anyone.

Comment: `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")` and again 
 `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")` ?? .. That's the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snip you posted does not compile. This makes helping you very difficult. Be sure to only post the minimum code required to reproduce the issue you are having. lastrowAD is not declared. You need to put `Option Explicit` at the top of EVERY module. This forces you to declare all of your variables. When you control the type of each variable you will no longer get type mismatches.

I can tell by your usage that `lastrowAD` is a Long. You are assigning your long with a range object. That is indeed a type mismatch. If we do what your code SAYS I can get the last row of column AD and that will solve the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, wkf As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
    AppendToColumn wks, "A", JobID.Text  'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last Blank Row
    AppendToColumn wks, "B", CoordName.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "C", PlannerName.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "D", Surveyor.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "E", RRGuy.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "F", DateBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "G", TimeBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "I", AddressBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "J", CityBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "K", PostcodeBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "L", THPBox.Text
    AppendToColumn wks, "M", JointBox.Text

    Dim lastrowG As Long, ListIndex As Long
    Dim lastrowAD As Long
    lastrowG = AppendToColumn(wks, "G", TimeBox.Text)
    lastrowAD = wks.Range("AD" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row
    AppendToColumn wks, "H", ("=G" & lastrowG & " + Formulas!AD" & lastrowAD)

    MsgBox ("All data has been added successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")` causing the error.

Comment: That is not the cause of the type mismatch error but you are correct that there is no way for us to tell which sheet he wants to use where

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error. Procedure will only consider the last Set wks and hence ther is no reference to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")` in the procedure. That is the cause of the error.

```
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
```

Also, I don't see how you are incrementing value of ListIndex. So, lastrowAD will always be = wks range AD1

Comment: That would not cause a `Type Mismatch` but it is a good observation

Answer (score -2):

I solved it eventually this way:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim wks As Worksheet, wkf As Worksheet
 Dim lastrowG As Long, lastrowL As Long, LastrowH As Long, LastrowS As Long, LastrowAF 
 As Long, LastrowAE As Long, ListIndex As Long
 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
 Set wkf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
AppendToColumn wks, "A", JobID.Text  'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last Blank Row
AppendToColumn wks, "B", CoordName.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "C", PlannerName.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "D", Surveyor.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "E", RRGuy.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "F", DateBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "G", TimeBox.Text
'AppendToColumn wks, "H", TimeEndBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "I", AddressBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "J", CityBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "K", PostcodeBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "L", THPBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "M", JointBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "N", FibreBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "O", FibreEquipmentBox.Text
AppendToColumn wks, "P", SpareFibreBox.Text

lLastrowG = wks.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastrowH = wks.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastrowL = wks.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastrowAF = wkf.Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'LastrowAE = Sheets("Formulas").Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 wkf.Range("AF" & LastrowAF).Formula = _
"=IF(Tracker!L" & lastrowL & "<20,""1:00"",""2:00"")"
'wkf.Range("AE" & LastrowAE).value = ("=Formulas!AD" & LastrowAD)
 wks.Range("H" & LastrowH).value = ("=G" & lastrowG & "+Formulas!AF" & LastrowAF)

MsgBox ("All data has been added successfully")
```

End Sub

where I parsed the Excel IF statement into the VBA code.